# Reducing the size of a figure saved in .EPS/.SVG format in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, svg, filesize, eps

Whenever saving a figure in R in .EPS or .SVG format, the size of the file is too large to be incorporated in an environment like Overleaf. How can I reduce the size? It feels rather unnecessary for a simple figure to be 141 mb (!).

This involves figures from the `ComplexUpset` package which formats via `ggplot2`

```
upset(
  M1_BinaryMatrix,
  colnames(M1_BinaryMatrix),
  sort_intersections_by='ratio',
  intersections='all',
  min_degree=2,
  
  set_sizes=(
    upset_set_size(position='right')
    + geom_text(aes(label=paste0(round((..count../nrow(M1_BinaryMatrix))*100), '%')), hjust=1.1, stat='count', color='white')
    + expand_limits(y=1000)
    + ylab("")
    + theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())
  ),
  #
  base_annotations=list(
    'Intersection ratio'=intersection_ratio(text_mapping=aes(label=!!upset_text_percentage()))
#    'Intersection ratio'= intersection_ratio(text_mapping=aes(label=paste0(round(
#      !!get_size_mode('inclusive_intersection')/!!nrow(head(M1_BinaryMatrix, 1000)) * 100
#    ), '%')))
    + ylab("") 
    + theme(axis.text.y=element_blank())
  ),
  #
  name="",
  wrap=TRUE,
  stripes=c(alpha('grey90', 0.45), alpha('white', 0.3)),
  matrix = intersection_matrix(    
    geom=geom_point(
      shape='square',
      size=4
    ),
    segment=geom_segment(
      linetype='solid'
    ), 
    outline_color=list(
      active='darkorange3',
      inactive='grey70'
    )
  )
) + labs(title = "", caption = "")
```

The data frame has 10 M rows and 3 columns.

Comment: @BenBolker Please refer to the first and second updated Q.

Comment: what are the dimensions of `M1_BinaryMatrix` in your example?

Comment: The dimensions are 10163286 rows and 3 columns, so rather large

Comment: Is this an adequate recipe for a reproducible example? `set.seed(101); nc <- 3; nr <- 1e6; M1_BinaryMatrix <- matrix(sample(0:1, size = nr*nc, replace =TRUE), nrow = nr, 
 dimnames = list(NULL,  1:nc)) |> as.data.frame()`

Comment: (how sparse is your binary matrix? how long does it take to generate the upset plot? I'm doing this on a laptop and it seems to be taking a long time ...)

Comment: Couple of minutes, quite long

Comment: I still have problems rendering this to a PDF at all, but the PDF I get is only about 1Mb (which still seems "too large"). Maybe post something here https://github.com/krassowski/complex-upset/issues ?

Comment: what is `mean(as.matrix(M1_BinaryMatrix))` (i.e. what degree of sparsity)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250928/discussion-between-sean-tbi-research-and-ben-bolker).

Comment: The rather obvious answer would seem to be:  once your plot-values are calculated, do a standard size reduction by summing rows and/or columns (with a smoothing kernel of your choice).